# Fitting Axis and of Y and X in Excel

Tags: excel, axis-labels, yaxis

I have the following Graph: [image: Graph] The Y values are located at X= 32,64,128,256, 512 and 1024. However, the graph shows different values. I would like to show for X-axis labels only the relevant values (i.e.32,64,128,256, 512 and 1024). 
In addition, I would like to add the maximal value of 1 to Y-axis. As can be seen I defined the maximal value to be 1 but the graph doesn't show it.
How can I fix these 2 issues both in X-axis and in Y-axis? 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the X-axis: tick the check box "Logarithmic scale" and set the Base to 2.

For the Y-axis: set the Minimum to a value that is divisible by the Major unit 0.1, for example to 0.4.

Thanks to Hans Vogelaar (http://www.eileenslounge.com) for the answer.